# Compare rows with duplicate value (in specified column) then remove rows based on criteria determined by their values in two other specified columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R similar to the one I have created below (for illustration). For accounts with a duplicated ID (in my example below the ID is a name, but could also be a number) I would like to write some code that, removes those rows for which the Closed values in the duplicated ID entries match the Opened value. For example below, the first three rows are 3 different accounts belonging to John (duplicate ID of "John" in the ID column). The first two (of that set of three) were both closed on 09/30/2017 (which matches the Opened value of the third), so they should be removed from the output data frame. Same for Mary (the Closed date of one of her two accounts matches the Opened date of the other, so the closed one should be removed). However, for Jack and Pete, both of their respective accounts should be kept in the output data frame because (in each case), the Closed date does not match the Opened date. All rows without any duplicate ID (e.g. Jill, Jane, Alice) are also kept in the output data frame.

I have the following code to filter by duplicate IDs using dplyr.

```
Input_DF_Dupl_ID <- Input_DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

However, it only identifies and arranges the duplicated accounts- it does not go on to remove the ones that meet the criteria defined above. Furthermore, I do not actually want to remove (filter out) the non-duplicated accounts.

I hope this is clear, appreciate all the help I can get., thanks in advance...

Input_DF:

```
Date       ID    Opened     Closed     Review      Status  Type Paid
09/30/2017 John  09/21/2016 09/30/2017 09/30/2019  Closed  A    1000
09/30/2017 John  06/19/2015 09/30/2017 06/30/2020  Closed  A    2500
09/30/2017 John  09/30/2017            14/31/2022  Open    A    0
09/30/2017 Jill  11/10/2014            07/31/2018  Open    B    0
09/30/2017 Jane  07/15/2012 09/30/2017 07/31/2017  Closed  C    10999
09/30/2017 Alice 06/19/2015 09/30/2017 06/30/2020  Closed  A    500
09/30/2017 Mary  11/10/2014 09/30/2017 07/31/2018  Closed  B    12000
09/30/2017 Mary  09/30/2017            07/31/2022  Open    B    0
09/30/2017 Jack  06/19/2011 09/30/2017 06/30/2020  Closed  A    500
09/30/2017 Jack  03/19/2015            06/30/2020  Open    A    0
09/30/2017 Pete  07/15/2012 05/31/2015 07/31/2017  Closed  B    0
09/30/2017 Pete  12/22/2016            07/31/2017  Open    C    0
```

Desired Output_DF:

```
Date       ID    Opened     Closed     Review      Status  Type Paid
09/30/2017 John  09/30/2017            14/31/2022  Open    A    0
09/30/2017 Jill  11/10/2014            07/31/2018  Open    B    0
09/30/2017 Jane  07/15/2012 09/30/2017 07/31/2017  Closed  C    10999
09/30/2017 Alice 06/19/2015 09/30/2017 06/30/2020  Closed  A    500
09/30/2017 Mary  09/30/2017            07/31/2022  Open    B    0
09/30/2017 Jack  06/19/2011 09/30/2017 06/30/2020  Closed  A    500
09/30/2017 Jack  03/19/2015            06/30/2020  Open    A    0
09/30/2017 Pete  07/15/2012 05/31/2015 07/31/2017  Closed  B    0
09/30/2017 Pete  12/22/2016            07/31/2017  Open    C    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code. Edited to apply the condition only to groups whose size is greater than one record

```
library(dplyr)
Input_DF_Dupl_ID <- Input_DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(!(Status == "Closed" & Closed %in% Open & n()>1)) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your help Sai, your elegant piece of code does 95% of the job. The only bug is that if there is an account without a duplicate ID but for which Closed date == Opened date, it also filters out that account (that filtering condition should only be applied to accounts for which there are duplicate IDs i.e. a customer with more than one account). e.g. in Input_DF above, if you change the Closed date value for Alice's account (ID "Alice") to 06/19/2015, that account will not appear in Output_DF despite not having a duplicate ID.

Comment: Hi Teejaydonjuan, Please find above edited code according to mentioned requirement

Comment: Thanks Sai, that works; really appreciate all your input!